# How can we depict a person who is keen to live in the countryside, keeping chicken, ducks & growing their own vegetables, etc?

Tags: expression-choice

A person with ‘gardening feelings’? Definitely not, but I don't know how exactly to say it.

Comment: Do you care about UK/US variation?

Comment: @Sakuratn please edit the question to include a sample sentence showing how the word or phrase will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person could be described as having an agrarian lifestyle.

> **agrarian** *adjective*
>
> **2 a :** of, relating to, or characteristic of farmers or their way of life
>            // *agrarian* values
>
> <sub>Source: [*Merriam-Webster* —
> agrarian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agrarian)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How about [rural](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rural) or [rustic](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rustic)?

From thefreedictionary.com:

> **ru·ral**  (ro͝or′əl) adj.
>
> 1. Of, relating to, or characteristic of the country.
> 2. Of or relating to people who live in the country: rural households.
> 3. Of or relating to farming; agricultural.

> **rustic** (ˈrʌstɪk) or **rustical** adj
>
> 1. of, characteristic of, or living in the country; rural
> 2. having qualities ascribed to country life or people; simple; unsophisticated: rustic pleasures.